# simple if statement with if

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to add a word into a string if it is not in there. And I converted the string into an `array(an)` like this and used push to add the new word but the new word is getting added `(an.length - 1)` times.

How can I fix this?

```
var ime = "open it now"
var an = ime.split(' ')
var ene = "itt"
for(var i = 0; i < ano.length; i++){

  if(an[i] != ene)

   an.push(ene) 

}
console.log(an)
```

Comment: what do you expect the output string to be?

Comment: i need the out put to be "open it now itt"

Answer (score 1):

You should be using indexOf and string concantenation

```
ime = ime.indexOf( ene ) === -1 ? ime + ' ' + ene : ime
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zGU/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method called `indexOf` for that you want.

For example:

```
var input = "you input string";
var word = "the word you are looking for";
// If the word you are looking for is not contained in you string,
// add it at the end of it.
if(input.indexOf(word)===-1)
{
    input = input + ' ' +word;
}
```

If you need more documenation about this method, `indexOf`, please have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) to check value present or not.

```
var ime = "open it now"
var an = ime.split(' ')
var ene = "itt";
if(an.indexOf(ene)==-1)
{
  an.push(ene);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zS68C/)**

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
var ime = "open it now";
var ene = "itt";
if(ime.indexOf(ene) < 0)
    ime += " "+ene;
console.log(ime);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work.

```
var ime = "open it now";
var ene = "itt";
var an = ime.split(' ')

if( an.indexOf(ene) == -1)
  ime += " "+ene;
console.log(ime);
```